# SQL Stored Proc For Search Query Based on Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, multiple-select-query

Ok, I need a little help with a stored proc, that is a little bit over my head and I am not sure how to proceed. The SP is for a search function in a project I am working on. It is to find available seats based on selections from the end user. The user should be able to search based on the following:

Departure airport (or "ANY")

Arrival airport (or "ANY")

Earliest Depart time

Latest Depart time

Min Seats Available

Max Flights to be Returned

I initially thought separate SELECT statements would do the trick, but as you probably know, the select statements were treated as separate queries and the return resulted in 6 different returns. So, I attempted to include them in one SELECT, but my logic must be screwy, because the return is faulty. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated. Code follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FindSeats]
(
@DepartureAirport           char(3),
@ArrivalAirport             char(3),
@EarliestDepTime            datetime,
@LatestDepTime              datetime,
@minSeatsAvailable          int,
@maxFlightsRequested        int

 )

AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(@DepartureAirport = UPPER('ANY') OR DepartAirport = @DepartureAirport)
AND
(@ArrivalAirport = UPPER('ANY') OR ArriveAirport = @ArrivalAirport) 
AND
(DepartTime >= @EarliestDepTime) 
AND
(DepartTime <= @LatestDepTime) 
AND
(FlightSeatsAvailiable >= @minSeatsAvailable) 
AND
((SELECT COUNT(FlightID) FROM Flight) <= @maxFlightsRequested)


--IF (@DepartureAirport = UPPER('ANY')) 
--BEGIN
--(SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE DepartAirport != '')
--END
--ELSE
--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE DepartAirport = @DepartureAirport


--IF (@ArrivalAirport = UPPER('ANY'))
--Begin
--(SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE ArriveAirport != '')
--END
--ELSE
--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE ArriveAirport = @ArrivalAirport


--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE DepartTime >= @EarliestDepTime

--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE DepartTime <= @LatestDepTime

--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE FlightSeatsAvailiable >= @minSeatsAvailable

--SELECT * FROM Flight WHERE (SELECT COUNT(FlightID) FROM Flight) <= @maxFlightsRequested
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql search query for multiple optional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333965/sql-search-query-for-multiple-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be, if i understand your need correctly:

SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(@DepartureAirport = UPPER('ANY') OR DepartAirport = @DepartureAirport)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(@ArrivalAirport = UPPER('ANY') OR ArriveAirport = @ArrivalAirport) 
AUNION
SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(DepartTime >= @EarliestDepTime) 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(DepartTime <= @LatestDepTime) 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
(FlightSeatsAvailiable >= @minSeatsAvailable) 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Flight
WHERE
((SELECT COUNT(FlightID) FROM Flight) <= @maxFlightsRequested)

this would aggregate all the results depending on user's input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. See my comment to @dillenmeister. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It really depends what parameters u are sending, try testing each parameter at a time and then adding another. Your original code was good but seems to me u are sending empty parameters that might mess up your SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FindSeats]
(
    @DepartureAirport           char(3),
    @ArrivalAirport             char(3),
    @EarliestDepTime            datetime,
    @LatestDepTime              datetime,
    @minSeatsAvailable          int,
    @maxFlightsRequested        int    
 )    
AS

SELECT  TOP(@maxFlightsRequested) * 
FROM    Flight
WHERE   (@DepartureAirport = 'any' OR DepartAirport = @DepartureAirport)
        AND (@ArrivalAirport = 'any' OR ArriveAirport = @ArrivalAirport) 
        AND DepartTime >= @EarliestDepTime
        AND DepartTime <= @LatestDepTime
        AND FlightSeatsAvailiable >= @minSeatsAvailable
```

Note that if you limit the number of rows returned, it's probably a good idea to sort the result in some way (ORDER BY).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its funny I tried both yours and @Sagi solutions--@Sagi's gave me all flights regardless of the parameters, and yours gave me no results. Where do you think I am going wrong?

Comment: Try these parameters (should be a wide search); `exec [usp_FindSeats] @DepartureAirport = 'any', @ArrivalAirport = 'any', @EarliestDepTime = '2000-01-01', @LatestDepTime = '2020-01-01', @minSeatsAvailable = 0, @maxFlightsRequested = 5`